# Datanucleus - Every second row is blank when composite keys used

Tags: java, excel, jpa, apache-poi, datanucleus

I've a MySQL table, with the following schema, and data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orderdetails` (
  `orderNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `productCode` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `quantityOrdered` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `priceEach` double NOT NULL,
  `orderLineNumber` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orderNumber`,`productCode`),
  KEY `productCode` (`productCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `orderdetails` (`orderNumber`, `productCode`, `quantityOrdered`, `priceEach`, `orderLineNumber`) VALUES
(10100, 'S18_1749', 30, 136, 3),
(10100, 'S18_2248', 50, 55.09, 2),
(10100, 'S18_4409', 22, 75.46, 4),
(10100, 'S24_3969', 49, 35.29, 1),
(10101, 'S18_2325', 25, 108.06, 4),
(10101, 'S18_2795', 26, 167.06, 1),
(10101, 'S24_1937', 45, 32.53, 3),
(10101, 'S24_2022', 46, 44.35, 2),
(10102, 'S18_1342', 39, 95.55, 2),
(10102, 'S18_1367', 41, 43.13, 1);

ALTER TABLE `orderdetails`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `orderdetails_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`productCode`) REFERENCES `products` (`productCode`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `orderdetails_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`orderNumber`) REFERENCES `orders` (`orderNumber`);
```

If I try to map theese Entities in the following ways:

### Way 1

Using the `@IdClass` annottion. I have an `OrderDetailsId` class:

```
public class OrderDetailsId implements Serializable {    
    private int orderNumber;    
    private String productCode;   

    public int hashCode() {
        return (int) productCode.hashCode() + orderNumber;
    }    

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof OrderDetailsId)) return false;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        OrderDetailsId pk = (OrderDetailsId) obj;
        return pk.orderNumber == orderNumber && pk.productCode.equals(productCode);
    }
}
```

And an `OrderDetails` class:

```
@IdClass(OrderDetailsId.class)
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDERDETAILS")
public class OrderDetails {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ORDERNUMBER")
    private int orderNumber;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PRODUCTCODE")
    private String productCode;

    @Column(name = "quantityOrdered")
    private int quantityOrdered;

    @Column(name = "priceEach")
    private double priceEach;

    @Column(name = "orderLineNumber")
    private int orderLineNumber;

}
```

When I try to persist some of this objects into an .xls file, it runs successfully, but every second row is blank. Here's the method:

```
public void exportSomeToXls() {
    OrderDetails o1 = getOrderDetails("S18_1749", 10100);
    OrderDetails o2 = getOrderDetails("S18_1750", 10101);
    OrderDetails o3 = getOrderDetails("S18_1751", 10102);
    OrderDetails o4 = getOrderDetails("S18_1752", 10103);
    OrderDetails o5 = getOrderDetails("S18_1753", 10104);
    EntityTransaction tx = xlsManager.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    xlsManager.persist(o1);
    xlsManager.persist(o2);
    xlsManager.persist(o3);
    xlsManager.persist(o4);
    xlsManager.persist(o5);
    tx.commit();
}

private OrderDetails getOrderDetails(String productCode, int orderNumber) {
    OrderDetails o1 = new OrderDetails();
    o1.setProductCode(productCode);
    o1.setOrderNumber(orderNumber);
    o1.setOrderLineNumber(1);
    o1.setPriceEach(136);
    o1.setQuantityOrdered(30);
    return o1;
}
```

And the result:

[image: Every second row is blank]

I also tried the stuff written in the [docs](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_3/jpa/primary_key.html), but still got a blank line between the data.

If I run this method on a MySQL datastore, not on an .xls datastore, the rows saved fine into the DB.

### Way 2

The other way, I tried, is with the `@Embeddable` annotation, with "Embedded" key. The `OrderDetailsId` class:

```
@Embeddable
public class OrderDetailsId implements Serializable {

    private int orderNumber;

    private String productCode;

    public int hashCode() {
        return (int) productCode.hashCode() + orderNumber;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof OrderDetailsId)) return false;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        OrderDetailsId pk = (OrderDetailsId) obj;
        return pk.orderNumber == orderNumber && pk.productCode.equals(productCode);
    }
}
```

The `OrderDetails` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDERDETAILS")
public class OrderDetails {

    private OrderDetailsId primaryKey;

    @Column(name = "quantityOrdered")
    private int quantityOrdered;

    @Column(name = "priceEach")
    private double priceEach;

    @Column(name = "orderLineNumber")
    private int orderLineNumber;

    @EmbeddedId
    public OrderDetailsId getPrimaryKey(){
        return primaryKey;
    }
}
```

And the method, which does the persisting:

```
public void exportSomeToXls() {
    OrderDetails o1 = getOrderDetails("S18_1749", 10100);
    OrderDetails o2 = getOrderDetails("S18_1750", 10101);
    OrderDetails o3 = getOrderDetails("S18_1751", 10102);
    OrderDetails o4 = getOrderDetails("S18_1752", 10103);
    OrderDetails o5 = getOrderDetails("S18_1753", 10104);
    EntityTransaction tx = xlsManager.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    xlsManager.persist(o1);
    xlsManager.persist(o2);
    xlsManager.persist(o3);
    xlsManager.persist(o4);
    xlsManager.persist(o5);
    tx.commit();
}

private OrderDetails getOrderDetails(String productCode, int orderNumber) {
    OrderDetailsId id = new OrderDetailsId();
    id.setOrderNumber(orderNumber);
    id.setProductCode(productCode);

    OrderDetails o1 = new OrderDetails();
    o1.setPrimaryKey(id);
    o1.setOrderLineNumber(1);
    o1.setPriceEach(136);
    o1.setQuantityOrdered(30);
    return o1;
}
```

In this case I get a NPE during Runtime, see the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.store.excel.fieldmanager.StoreFieldManager.<init>(StoreFieldManager.java:90)
    at org.datanucleus.store.excel.ExcelPersistenceHandler.insertObject(ExcelPersistenceHandler.java:153)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractPersistenceHandler.insertObjects(AbstractPersistenceHandler.java:71)
    at org.datanucleus.flush.FlushNonReferential.flushDeleteInsertUpdateGrouped(FlushNonReferential.java:190)
    at org.datanucleus.flush.FlushNonReferential.execute(FlushNonReferential.java:60)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.flushInternal(ExecutionContextImpl.java:3987)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.flush(ExecutionContextImpl.java:3932)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.preCommit(ExecutionContextImpl.java:4098)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.transactionPreCommit(ExecutionContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.internalPreCommit(TransactionImpl.java:388)
    at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:277)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityTransaction.commit(JPAEntityTransaction.java:98)
    at com.example.poc.daos.OrderDetailsDao.exportSomeToXls(OrderDetailsDao.java:48)
    at com.example.poc.Main.main(Main.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:290)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

### Question

Is there any way, to use DataNucleus with composite keys?

Comment: Never tried with composite keys on my app. From what I know it was developed around their JDO support so the second option would be unlikely to work, and other non-RDBMS plugins certainly don't support EmbeddedId. Suggest you grab the code (its not large from what I remember) and debug your way through it ... ExcelPersistenceHandler/StoreFieldManager

Comment: Other thing you could do is try the same with the "datanucleus-odf" plugin (which would create a spreadsheet file equally readable into Excel, since ODF is an international standard after all).

Comment: Thanks, the `datanucleus-odf` plugin works. I think I'm not capable of debugging the excel plugin. Should I create a small example of this, and report them as a bug, or?

Comment: definitely, nobody will know about it if not reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug. Reported, will be fixed in the next release. See:

http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/forum/viewthread_thread,7835_offset,0#37884

Thanks @Neil Stockton for the help!